# Big fonts and dialogs in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Today I installed Windows 7 in a Dell Studio laptop I have.

The problem is that everything is really big, the letters, fonts, dialogs, pretty much everything is bigger than it should be. The clock icons look ugly because of that.

I would like to know what do I have to change to get it working. I didn't have that problem in Vista, is it some kind of problem with Windows 7? The graphic card is an ATI HD 4570 with the latest drivers from the support page at Dell.

[image]

I've changed some of the font sizes via the "Advanced appearance settings" but the icons in the system tray keep looking ugly and some fonts and dialogs keep being big. Where can that be changed? Isn't there a master thing to change it all? I'm guessing that changing the individual font sizes as I did is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your DPI settings gone wrong? (Search for DPI in control panel, click on display, then it's in the sidebar)

Comment: Thank you! That was the "problem" it was set to 125%, setting it to 100% made it look as it should.

Answer (score 0):

if 100% DPI is still to big for your taste, you can edit the registry to go below the minimum limit imposed by Microsoft:

Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG, Software, Fonts`

Name=LogPixels value is 96 decimal. (100 percent)

For 90 percent font size, set to 86 decimal.

For 80 percent font size, set to 76 decimal.

Log Off for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for the appointment, 100% was enough, it was set to 125% by default making it look strange.

Comment: you're welcome, keep this 'trick' in mind, it might come in handy someday.

Comment: Yes, it's already in a kind of snippet-trick file I have ;)